# Choosing between UIIMagePickerController and AVFoundation

Tags: ios7, uiimagepickercontroller, avfoundation

I have app, which takes photos, crops them to fit display and uses it as overlay for next photo. I use UIIMagePickerController for that, and it works perfectly for me, however I realized I need to take photos only in landscape orientation. As it's written in [UIImagePickerController class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html), it supports portrait mode only. I know there are several workarounds, and it is possible to use it in landscape, but I've red that there's a risk Apple will reject my app.

On the other hand, AVFoundation looks like a bit overkill for my needs.
Do I really need to use AVFoundation?

Answer (score 2):

I'd use AVFoundation since its much more flexible than ImagePicker, it's always a good idea to future proof your design. And it's not all that tough to set up an AVCapture session, just look at the Demo Apps and see how it's done.